# ffmpeg mediocre conversion quality from DVD

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.265

I am trying to convert a DVD that I own into mp4/lib265 format. To test the quality out I am only converting the first two minutes of the input video (which is a concatenated vob file). The source video is not particularly high resolution being a DVD it is `720x480`

- I tried 8/10/12 bit hevc
- For a 720p video I usually go crf-22 and for 1080p crf-20 and usually happy with these values. This dvd is lower resolution than that, I tried going as low as crf-18
- I use `min-keyint` and `keyint` parameters always, as I keep them very low to increase seeking performance. These being low enough should not decrease quality but I tried with even lower `min-keyint` just in case.

**Problem:** In the video whenever camera moves, I can see huge pixels across all details on screen. The camera movement is not even particularly fast. For example it moves from the belt level of the main character to face in approximately 2 seconds.

**Question:**
Can someone possibly point out what I am doing wrong or what else to do, to fix this. or may be some fine tuning parameters?

**Command ran for testing:**

```
ffmpeg ^
-i "ConCat2.vob" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=5:keyint=50"  -preset slow -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "08 bit.crf20.ki05.mp4"  ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=5:keyint=50"  -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "10 bit.crf20.ki05.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=5:keyint=50"  -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p12le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "12 bit.crf20.ki05.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "08 bit.crf20.ki25.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "10 bit.crf20.ki25.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=20:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p12le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "12 bit.crf20.ki25.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=18:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "08 bit.crf18.ki25.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=18:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "10 bit.crf18.ki25.mp4" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -x265-params  "crf=18:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p12le -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "12 bit.crf18.ki25.mp4"
```

**ffprobe for input:**

```
ffprobe version 4.3.1-2020-10-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'ConCat2.vob':
  Duration: 01:26:30.42, start: 0.300300, bitrate: 5891 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, bottom first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7500000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

**ffmpeg encoding result summary screen:**

```
x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:19.75  kb/s: 15050.33
x265 [info]: frame P:    902, Avg QP:21.58  kb/s: 12471.95
x265 [info]: frame B:   2621, Avg QP:26.88  kb/s: 3518.91
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.5% UV:5.9%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 3.7% 2.2% 39.7% 30.9% 23.6%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.04s (1.13 fps), 6001.25 kb/s, Avg QP:25.41
[aac @ 000001a27fe3ccc0] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:19.78  kb/s: 15170.72
x265 [info]: frame P:    890, Avg QP:21.60  kb/s: 12635.53
x265 [info]: frame B:   2633, Avg QP:26.82  kb/s: 3698.17
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.4% UV:7.6%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 3.7% 2.4% 35.9% 33.0% 25.0%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.02s (1.13 fps), 6145.55 kb/s, Avg QP:25.38
[aac @ 000001a200728f80] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:20.40  kb/s: 14358.58
x265 [info]: frame P:    813, Avg QP:22.09  kb/s: 12347.13
x265 [info]: frame B:   2710, Avg QP:26.81  kb/s: 3986.21
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:14.5% UV:13.0%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 1.1% 1.9% 20.0% 44.3% 32.7%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.01s (1.13 fps), 6089.35 kb/s, Avg QP:25.61
[aac @ 000001a20072b880] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:19.78  kb/s: 15063.06
x265 [info]: frame P:    903, Avg QP:21.57  kb/s: 12490.80
x265 [info]: frame B:   2620, Avg QP:26.88  kb/s: 3506.11
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.4% UV:5.6%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 2.9% 2.6% 40.9% 30.8% 22.8%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.01s (1.13 fps), 5999.41 kb/s, Avg QP:25.40
[aac @ 000001a2005343c0] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:19.81  kb/s: 15185.65
x265 [info]: frame P:    888, Avg QP:21.59  kb/s: 12655.86
x265 [info]: frame B:   2635, Avg QP:26.82  kb/s: 3687.45
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.8% UV:7.8%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 2.7% 2.4% 37.5% 33.1% 24.3%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.01s (1.13 fps), 6138.05 kb/s, Avg QP:25.39
[aac @ 000001a200537a80] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:20.41  kb/s: 14386.07
x265 [info]: frame P:    815, Avg QP:22.09  kb/s: 12322.46
x265 [info]: frame B:   2708, Avg QP:26.80  kb/s: 3988.57
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:14.7% UV:13.1%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 0.9% 1.2% 20.8% 46.5% 30.6%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.02s (1.13 fps), 6090.74 kb/s, Avg QP:25.60
[aac @ 000001a200538cc0] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:17.78  kb/s: 17517.32
x265 [info]: frame P:    903, Avg QP:19.57  kb/s: 15024.90
x265 [info]: frame B:   2620, Avg QP:24.80  kb/s: 4860.86
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.4% UV:5.6%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 2.9% 2.6% 40.9% 30.8% 22.8%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.02s (1.13 fps), 7672.84 kb/s, Avg QP:23.34
[aac @ 000001a2005363c0] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:17.81  kb/s: 17620.88
x265 [info]: frame P:    888, Avg QP:19.59  kb/s: 15156.42
x265 [info]: frame B:   2635, Avg QP:24.74  kb/s: 5070.71
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.8% UV:7.8%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 2.7% 2.4% 37.5% 33.1% 24.3%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.02s (1.13 fps), 7818.79 kb/s, Avg QP:23.33
[aac @ 000001a20053b5c0] Qavg: 314.316

x265 [info]: frame I:     74, Avg QP:18.41  kb/s: 16755.65
x265 [info]: frame P:    815, Avg QP:20.09  kb/s: 14822.84
x265 [info]: frame B:   2708, Avg QP:24.71  kb/s: 5464.50
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:14.7% UV:13.1%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 0.9% 1.2% 20.8% 46.5% 30.6%

encoded 3597 frames in 3196.02s (1.13 fps), 7817.18 kb/s, Avg QP:23.53
[aac @ 000001a2006cb940] Qavg: 314.316
```

Comment: Probably not even worth asking, but if you play `ConCat2.vob` does it show the same problem? Just want to verify it is not present in the source.

Comment: no the problem does not exist in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several things before actually landing on the answer for my particular problem, writing them down here in case some of them might help others.

- Tried disabling sao with "no-sao=1" no improvments.
- played with `psy-rd`, `rdoq` and `psy-rdoq` parameters with very high and very low values no significant improvements
- decreased `ctu` to `ctu=16` with no improvements.
- many people suggests h265 is more successful with high-res videos rather than old low res ones. I tried switching to h264 with no significant changes (except file size!)
- at this point I gave up, for a last try I removed all my parameters and encoded h265 with `CRF=1 -preset slower` just to see what'll happen. This produced as expected a gigantic file took ages and still produced the same result.
- I jumped on to handbrake and did an h264 encoding with default settings, I noticed the problem was gone (despite using the same underlying library)
- used handbrake with default settings for h265 and again the problem was gone again despite using the same underlying library.
- compared debug output of handbrake and ffmpeg, I noticed only significant difference was handbrake was applying `decomb` which is a deinterlacing filter.
- I don't have decomb compiled into my current ffmpeg but I tried `yadif` with `-vf yadif` and boom the artifacts are gone! the problem was the interlaced video. I tried some other deinterlacing algorithms as well like `bwdif` and `nnedi` where all of them resolved the problem. `nnedi` produced the best results but also took significantly longer.
- Finally added my other options back and the problem is still resolved. For reference the final command I used to convert this particular DVD to h265:

```
ffmpeg ^
-i "ConCat2.vob" ^
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -vf yadif -x265-params  "crf=22:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" -preset slow -map 0:1 -map 0:2 "08 bit.crf22.yadif.mp4"
```